# Cloning a PDB from one CDB into another CDB with TDE enabled at source and target

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, transparent-data-encryption

What are the possible ways to Clone a PDB from one CDB into another CDB (in a different host) with TDE enabled at both source and target.

At present i am able to think of the following two

a) Data pump export and import

b) Unplugging in source and plugging into target

Option a) requires creation of tablespaces manually before import at target pdb and is quite slow since the data we have is huge.

Option b) is easy without TDE but with TDE their is a concept of exporting and importing encryption keys , and what ever i have used it till now it becomes quite complex during plugging and importing keys .

Can someone suggest and alternative way to achieve the mentioned requirement or may be a way to do a) or b) with more ease and accuracy .

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid exportation of encryption keys, your only chance is Data Pump, because that's the whole purpose of TDE.

Yes, you have different ways to clone your PDB, such Data Guard, but you'll need to export the encryption keys too.